# X-axis doesn't show correct time

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using "Time data with irregular intervals" chart. xaxis data is in epoch time and it's range is 12:00 PM till 15:00 PM. The problem is that despite time range is from 12:00 PM till 15:00 PM but Highcharts xaxis labels range is 9:00 AM till 12:00 PM, that is completely wrong! What's the problem ?
thnx.

Comment: You really need to show us some code. We can't help you blind. You've asked 3 questions, all on highcharts. Have you considered taking a long, good look at the [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use#options) [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the timerange (of 3 hours) is ok, I'll take a wild guess and say it's the Timezone. But as JamWaffles says: Without code, we can do nothing but wild guesses.

By the way: what is "15 PM"? I guess you are talking about the timeranges 
1200 - 1500 and 0900-1200 or 12 PM - 3 PM and 9 AM - 12 PM

Comment: Well, it was a  Timezone problem. thnx you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, this was a TZ issue as Fildor mentioned.  If you want the values to be in UTC, you should specify the following in the options:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
global: {
    useUTC: false
}
});
```

As mentioned here:

[Receiving incorrect datetimes when using milliseconds for x-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791859/receiving-incorrect-datetimes-when-using-milliseconds-for-x-axis)