# Receiving incorrect datetimes when using milliseconds for x-axis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is a link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jx5n2/2868/). For some reason my datetimes are showing up incorrectly as you can see below.

I have confirmed that the milliseconds were correct so I'm led to believe that it's a bug with the library however I've seen examples using Date.UTC that work correctly but I can't seem to find any examples in their documentation that uses milliseconds instead.

Millisecond values were: 1326113281133,1326113401128, 1326113521102, 1326113641108,1326113761129,1326113881139,1326114001156,1326114241198.

Any help would be much appreciated in helping to find out the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 5):

its not a bug in the library, the timestamps are shifted to Universal Time in the chart.

use the following code before your chart variable declaration

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
global: {
    useUTC: false
}
});
```

here is the reference to use this option
http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#global--useUTC

Comment: As it is with my production code, if you try to add this option in the jsfiddle it has no effect.